# How do I know The attributes of built-in class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I use Tkinter gui library for python . when we come to create root main window we write
root=Tk() 
I want to undetstand what happens inside Tk() , so how to know the attributes and function ?
(Python3)

Comment: Have you tried `dir(Tk)`?

Comment: yes but that was the result , <built-in method __dir__ of Tk object at 0x02AF3130>

Comment: Um… no it doesn't. `dir(Tk)` gives you a list of about 258 methods. `help(Tk)` gives you a 45-page help document that explains all the public ones. You can also find docs online. As with everything else in the stdlib, there's [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). From there, or Google, you can find [reference docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html), the [book](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/), and the [wiki](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/), among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Import Tk, then call `dir` or `help`:

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> help(tk.Tk) 
<lots of useful information>
```